# QGIS: Calculating change in grid shapefile statics

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics

I have two shapefiles which has two attribute information like below:

| fid | DN |
| --- | --- |
| 217536 | 2 |
| 217537 | 4 |
| 217538 | 6 |
| 217539 | 8 |
| 217540 | 10 |
| 217541 | 11 |
| 217852 | 3 |
| 217853 | 5 |

Both shapefiles have square grid of 250 x 250 Meter which has `DN` values and files has similar headers one is `FID` and Second is `DN` Values.

Both file has similar projection and nicely coming over each other in QGIS GUI.

I want to calculate the change in `DN` values within each vector grids. But there is no common filed on which basis I can pick the value i.e., fid is different for both shapefiles.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide the two shapefiles (dummy data) or post at least a screenshot? Not exactly clear what result you expect and where. What do you mean by `calculate the change in DN values within each vector grids`?

Answer (score 3):

I assume your grids overlap exactly, or very close to.

1. `Join attributes by location` to join the DN field of the second grid to the first. Join type = "Take attributes of the feature with largest overlap only (one to one)"
2. The output will have a new field named DN_2. Field Calculate the change `"DN_2"-"DN"`

[image]